# when to set up a mail server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email-server, email

i've got a web service up and running with apache on ubuntu server in a vps from a hosting company (long sentence:)).

i wonder when someone would like to set up a own mail server (postfix + dovecot)?

cause i just want to be able to:

1. send emails (account activation etc) to my users with php - the emails have to appear to come from the website's domain
2. receive emails from my users (customer support etc) using Apple Mail/Microsoft Outlook.

could this be accomplished with an email hosting company? are there situations i would benefit from setting up an own mail server on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set up your own mail server for that. The first can be mostly accomplished by setting headers as desired, and the second by using a service such as GMail's [business offering](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/gmail.html).

Comment: what do you mean by setting headers as desired? and if i use gmail's business offering, could i use my own domain?

Comment: The `$additional_headers` argument of `mail()`. Consult GMail's business FAQ if you have questions about it.

Comment: Actually having your own email server can still be good for sending. Just not accepting - but dumping the emails to a local server means any issue with network latency etc. is responsibility of the mail server, not the website script.

Comment: @tomtom. so in sum up: postfix good for sending not receiving, and dovecot just bad?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you keep your mail out of the VPS or on a second VPS for security reasons. not being able to answer mails when a server goes down isn't an option. I'm a big fan of hosted emails, they do all the work for you and most of the time it is cheap. A second VPS cost at least 20$ per month while hosted emails cost a lot less.

Comment: but if i want to be able to send mail from php script (in my first vps), then i have to set up a mail server (postfix) on either the same vps or another? or could one use an external smtp server (the sender's domain will be my own domain)? please shed a light on this

Comment: You dont need any MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) such as Postfix, sendmail, Qmail, etc. Php mail() function will handle the outgoing of emails. I am not aware of any requirement for mail() to work­. You would install an MTA if you have local mailboxes.